# pandas: restructuring DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe and baseline value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {'yr': 2010, 'month': 0, 'name': 'Johnny', 'total': 50},,
    {'yr': 2010, 'month': 0, 'name': 'Johnny', 'total': 50},
    {'yr': 2010, 'month': 1, 'name': 'Johnny', 'total': 105},
    {'yr': 2010, 'month': 0, 'name': 'Zack', 'total': 90}
])
baseline_value = 100
```

I'm grouping and aggregating the data based on year, month and name. Then I'm calculating the net sum relative to the baseline value:

```
pt = pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=['yr', 'month', 'name'], values='total', aggfunc=np.sum)
pt['net'] = pt['total'] - baseline_value
print(pt)
                    total    net
yr    month  name
2010  0      Johnny   100      0
             Zack      90    -10
      1      Johnny   105      5
```

How can I restructure this DataFrame so the output looks something like this:

```
                             value
yr    month   name    type
2010  0       Johnny  Total    100
                      Net        0
              Zack    Total     90
                      Net      -10
      1       Johnny  Total    105
                      Net        5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Option 1: Reshaping yout pivot dataframe: pt

Use `stack`, `rename`, and `to_frame`:

```
pt.stack().rename('value').to_frame()
```

Output:

```
                         value
yr   month name               
2010 0     Johnny total    100
                  net        0
           Zack   total     90
                  net      -10
     1     Johnny total    105
                  net        5
```

> Option 2 using `set_index` and `sum` from original df

Here is another approach starting from your source df, using `set_index` and `sum` with `level` parameter, then reshape with `stack`:

```
baseline_value = 100
(df.set_index(['yr','month','name'])
  .sum(level=[0,1,2])
  .eval('net = @baseline_value - total',inplace=False)
  .stack()
  .to_frame(name='value'))
```

Output:

```
                         value
yr   month name               
2010 0     Johnny total    100
                  net        0
           Zack   total     90
                  net       10
     1     Johnny total    105
                  net       -5
```

Comment: Nice! Looks like `pt.stack().to_frame(name='value')` works too

Comment: Yep, I forget that name parameter in to_frame.

Comment: @jcmetz21... Updated answer with a different approach using 'set_index` and `sum`.